# Mentioning different ids in a JS call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is a really simple question, I'm using a JQuery lightSlider that supports various instances on one page. In the code below, as you can see, everytime I create a new slider, I have to call the whole script again with the according ID of the slider.

My question is, is there any way to call all the diffent IDS inside the $("#lightSlider") or something like that ?

Just to make it clear, I already tried to use the same ID for all of the instances but it doesn't work.

The lightSlider I'm using is this one: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider

Code:

```
           <div class="box" id="box1">
                    <ul id="lightSlider"> <!--Slides-->
                        <li><img src="../1S.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../2S.png"/></li>
                    </ul>
           </div>

            <div class="box" id="box2">
                    <ul id="lightSlider2">
                        <li><img src="../1S.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../2S.png"/></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>


<!--This is for the first one-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
          item: 1,
          pager: false,
          controls: false,
          loop: true,
          slideMargin: 0,
          auto: true,
          pause: 2000,
          speed: 1000,
          pauseOnHover: true,
      }); 
    });
  </script> 


<!--This is for the second one-->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#lightSlider2").lightSlider({
          item: 1,
          pager: false,
          controls: false,
          loop: true,
          slideMargin: 0,
          auto: true,
          pause: 2000,
          speed: 1000,
          pauseOnHover: true,
      }); 
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried combining multiple ids in the jQuery selector? e.g. `$("#lightSlider, #lightSlider2")`

Comment: You can refactor that code very easily: `const options = { item: 1, ... }` is an obvious first step. Next you don't need two <script>s, you can use a single `$(document).ready(function () {` and `});` wrapper to call both `$("#lightSlider").lightSlider(options);` and `$("#lightSlider2").lightSlider(options);` Finally, if you add `class="slider"` to your <ul>s, you can simply do `$('.slider').lightSlider(options);` (note that none of this is really specific to jQuery or sliders, it's all about understanding the language basics of JS and eliminating duplicate code)

Comment: You don't *have* to use IDs. It's a selector. Give them the same class instead.